# Where do I put the iWebkit download?

Tags: webkit

I've downloaded it from [this](http://snippetspace.com/) website, and I'm trying to figure out where to put the download. I have a laptop running as a server for a website and I'm using XAMP to host my webpage. I've heard that I should put the files in /framework/.. in the root (C:/) of that laptop, that I should put it within XAMP, and various other places, but it never seems to work. Could somebody who is familiar with iWebKit help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right in the root folder of your website. The index.html page will be your homepage